# Flutter Navigator.pushNamed() context

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to redirect to another page using Navigator.pushNamed but I am getting an error.

This is exactly the error I get;

```
   The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
   Receiver: null
   Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()**
```

My codes (I use navigatorservice.);

```
class CalendarPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return _CalendarPageState();
}
}

class _CalendarPageState extends State {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    SfGlobalLocalizations.delegate
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('tr'),
  ],
  locale: const Locale('tr'),
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: SfCalendar(
        onTap: testOnTap,
        view: CalendarView.month,
        dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getDataSource()),
        monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
            showAgenda: true,
            appointmentDisplayMode:
                MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment),
       ),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Navigation:

```
if (reItem == datetest) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
        _CalendarPageState().context, CalendarDataGridRoute);
```

testOnTap:

```
void testOnTap(CalendarTapDetails details) {
if (details.targetElement == CalendarElement.agenda) {
final dates = <ClickedDate>[];
dates.add(ClickedDate(details.date));
final datetest = dates[0].date.year.toString() +
    "-" +
    dates[0].date.month.toString() +
    "-" +
    dates[0].date.day.toString();
List<Meeting> list = _getDataSource();
for (var item in list) {
  final reItem = item.baslangic.year.toString() +
      "-" +
      item.baslangic.month.toString() +
      "-" +
      item.baslangic.day.toString();
  if (reItem == datetest) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
        _CalendarPageState().context, CalendarDataGridRoute);
  }
}
```

I'm probably using the wrong context, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, you are not using the correct context. Can you directly send your context as parameter?

Comment: When I want to send it as a parameter, 1 parameter is missing. But it works fine if I don't add any parameters. testOnTap(context) = Wants 2 parameter(CalendarTapDetails) testOntap =working.

Comment: Can you add testOnTap method into your question too?

Comment: I added what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any `BuildContext` object you like. In your case you're creating a new instance of the state that doesn't exist in the tree and whose context is null.

You need to use context that has a `Navigator` as its ancestor. It appear you're trying to use the `MaterialApp` navigator, so you need context that is below that. The current context you have is above the `MaterialApp` so you need to use a `Builder` to get context below it.

```dart
class _CalendarPageState extends State {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    SfGlobalLocalizations.delegate
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('tr'),
  ],
  locale: const Locale('tr'),
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Builder(//Wrap the place where you need new context with a Builder
        builder: (newContext) {
          return SfCalendar(
            onTap: (details) {
              testOnTap(details, newContext);//Use newContext and modified testOnTap method here
            },
            view: CalendarView.month,
            dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getDataSource()),
            monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
              showAgenda: true,
              appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment
            ),
         );
      ),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

You'll also have you modify your `testOnTap` to take this context:

```dart
void testOnTap(CalendarTapDetails details, BuildContext context) {//Take context as another parameter
if (details.targetElement == CalendarElement.agenda) {
final dates = <ClickedDate>[];
dates.add(ClickedDate(details.date));
final datetest = dates[0].date.year.toString() +
    "-" +
    dates[0].date.month.toString() +
    "-" +
    dates[0].date.day.toString();
List<Meeting> list = _getDataSource();
for (var item in list) {
  final reItem = item.baslangic.year.toString() +
      "-" +
      item.baslangic.month.toString() +
      "-" +
      item.baslangic.day.toString();
  if (reItem == datetest) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
        context, CalendarDataGridRoute);//Pass the received context here
  }
}
```